# F# errors in Interactive but not in command line REPL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

This is erroring when run in Visual Studio F# Interactive window, but not in the command line F# REPL or in Rider.

```fsharp
let numbers = [1..10]
let numberFilter number = number % 5 = 0 || number % 3 = 0
;;
```

```
error FS0193: internal error: Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
```

- What's the index that's not found
- Why does it only work in the command line REPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that Visual Studio had got it's knickers in a twist.

Right click and reset on the F# window cured the problem.  Still don't know what caused it though.